# Блок "Метод оплаты" на странице "Оформление заказа" WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ecommerce

Друзья, проблема, которую я опишу ниже, возникает только в браузере Edge и IE. Во всех остальных браузерах все работает нормально.

Данный блок всегда остается недоступным, вечно находится в состоянии "Загрузка", как показано на скриншоте ниже:
[image: И вот в таком состоянии этот блок и находится]

Как вы понимаете, это не позволяет клиентам совершать покупку через данные браузеры.

У кого-нибудь есть какие-либо предположения о причине данной ошибки? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: В консоле должна быть ошибка js кода, по ней все можно понять

Answer (score 2):

Некоторые плагины, использующие JavaScript не тестируются (или плохо тестируются) с браузерами ei и edge. Ошибки таких плагинов останавливают работу JavaScript и, соответственно, не дают обновить блок с данными. Такие ошибки видны в консоли браузера.
По очереди отключите все плагины использующие JavaScript и таким образом выявите проблемный плагин, отключите его и все заработает.

Comment: @Эникейщик, у человека нет достаточного рейтинга, чтобы оставлять комментарии, однако его сообщение полезно и уж никак не заслуживает "минуса".

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Я и не ставил минус.

Comment: @Эникейщик я обознался :). А вообще есть проблема, когда комментарий нового участника с низким рейтингом полезен, но дотягивает до ответа, как в этом случае.